# How to Receive Data in batches in Spark Stream From RabbitMQ Message Queue

Tags: java, apache-spark, rabbitmq, streaming

I am new to Spark and I am developing a Simple Spark Streaming application that takes Excel Data having around 300 rows and continuously puts each row into RabbitMQ Queue(every 2 seconds) as Serialized Object. On the Other side - I need to pull that data from the Queue, Deserialize that received Object and do some manipulation on that object. But I also need to do this manipulation in parallel - So I thought of using Spark Streaming which performs actions on batches of sequence of deserialized objects.

Main.java

```
      String Row="";
      String Col[];
       String Parameters="";
       QueueConsumer consumer = new QueueConsumer("queue");
       Thread consumerThread = new Thread(consumer);
      consumerThread.start();
       Producer producer = new Producer("queue");

     try {

    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("somedata.csv"));  

    while(true) {
        Row = buffer.readLine();
        if(Row == null){
            break; // Stop at the End of the File or Last line
        } else {
            Col = Row.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)"); 
            for(int i=0;i<Col.length;i++) {
                Parameters += Col[i]+",";
            }
            if (Parameters.endsWith(",")) {
                Parameters = Parameters.substring(0, Parameters.length() - 1);
            }
            // Add Data from CSV to Object
            DataBuilder d = DataBuilder.addData(Parameters);
            Parameters="";
            producer.sendMessage(d);
            // Wait Until Object is Received ....
            Thread.sleep(666);
            //d=null;

        }
    }
    // Close the Buffer
    buffer.close();
 }catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error reading the File !");
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Producer.java

It has code that serializes object and puts them into Queue

Consumer.java

```
  /**
    * Called when consumer is registered.
   */
    public void handleConsumeOk(String consumerTag) {
       System.out.println("Consumer "+consumerTag +" registered");      
    }

   /**
     * Called when new message is available.
    */
public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope env,BasicProperties 
props, byte[] body) throws IOException {
try {
SparkConf conf = new 
SparkConf().setAppName("SparkStreaming").setMaster("local[*]");
JavaStreamingContext jssc = new 
JavaStreamingContext(conf,Durations.seconds(2));
 JavaReceiverInputDStream<Object> ReceiverStream = 
RabbitMQUtils.createStreamFromAQueue(jssc, "localhost", 5672, "queue", 
StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2)
```

// CODE TO BE ADDED HERE

```
    // Removing data from Queue
        try{
            d = (DataBuilder)SerializationUtils.deserialize(body);
            System.out.println(d.getDate().toString());
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

// Start the computation
try {
    jssc.start(); 
    jssc.awaitTermination();    
}
catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}

}
```

My Simple Question is How to Receive Data in Batches using Spark Streaming and RabbitMQ 
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: have you solved this ?

Comment: Yes. I have figured to solved this problem. Thanks

Comment: good! why cant you post the solution as answer then, people with the same problem can refer from here

Comment: this should be answer not a comment :-)

Comment: Sure.. I was facing the problem of Connection refused for RabbitMQUtils.createStreamFromAQueue(jssc, "localhost", 5672, "queue", StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2) because RabbitMQ Consumer program was connected to Producer program. So Spark Streaming was not forming any batches because it couldn't able to connect to RabbitMQ Producer. But later I removed all Rabbit MQ Receivers and kept only Spark Streaming as my Receiver which started working for me :)  There is some problem in posting my answer, So I have put my answer here in the comment section